# Get size of dynamic iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am using this code to load an iframe dynamically from the user.( the url and `iframeid` are variables).
Once the iframe is loaded i want to get the height of the page to set it on the actual iframe.

```
    $("#iframeid").prop("src", src); // set the dynamic url

        $("#iframeid").on("load", function() {
           

            var body = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
                html = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow.document.documentElement;

            var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);

           
            $("#iframeid").height(height + "px");
            console.log(height);// displays 397

        });
```

The result keeps the iframe size as 397 (no idea why it is not 400 as I assigned it)

The iframe that i am loading this url to has the followings css:

```
.diviframe {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
}
```

I have tried making the iframe with 100% `width` and `height` but it gives a result of 8 in the `console.log(height)` and gives a `height` of 4 to the iframe which doesnt make sence.

I dont mind the small differences but i want to actually get the page height.

Comment: Greetings and welcome to Stack Overflow! can you please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time, I have tried making a working example in code pen [Link in here](https://codepen.io/KhAzZaKa/pen/oNbOrZq) it might be something wrong with my jquery that is causing this issue? please have a look. thanks